# razor function call - NullReferenceException

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

here's a very simple class (Test.cs)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcApplication5.Models
{
    public class Test 
    {
        public string add(string s)
        {
            return s + "blaaaaa";
        }

    }
}
```

and a view (Index.cshtml)

```
@model MvcApplication5.Models.Test
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Homepage";
}

@Model.add("test")
```

I get a System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object, but I don't know why.

thanks, roxor :)

Comment: Visual Studio has a powerful debugger. You'd be doing yourself a tremendous favor if you learn how to use it. If the error occurs in that code, it may be because `s` is null. Is it? Who calls this?

Comment: You really don't want to be calling methods on a Model from a View. The only time you would call a method would be for HTML helpers. If you want to display information that you get from calling a method in the Model, you should call it from the controller and then pass in the result into the View (preferably using a ViewModel, or ViewData)

Comment: thx to all. @Queti yes it's a helper - I will try it tomorrow

Comment: the view should be the layout.cshtml. Should I create a controller for this view?

Answer (score 2):

You have to create an instance of your model

```
var myModel = new MvcApplication5.Models.Test()
```

and pass it to a view via a controller.  Check out some beginner mvc guides to see how to write a controller.